# Autocomplete dropdown text not taking full width

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

I am working on application and I have AutoComplete. I am inflating its adapter just as below

```
private void setAdapterActPreferredLocations(ArrayList<Locations> list) {

    if (list != null) {
        ArrayAdapter<Locations> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Locations>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_nothiong_selected_material, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_nothiong_selected_material);

        autoComplete.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(null);

        autoComplete.setDropDownWidth(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels);


    } else {
        autoComplete.setAdapter(null);
    }
}
```

**The R.layout.spinner goes like this**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="@string/select_store"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:typeface="normal"
    />
```

I have locations name . But my Locations name is not taking drop down full width. Let suppose the Location name is **PKVSParkline view point 113b**, but I am only looking PKVSParkline rest of words gets chopped. Where as there is penalty of space remaining. and ther is no doubt that whole name can be easily shown in available width.

When I click on that Item, I can see whole name gets set in the AutoComplete. I do not know what is the real problem. Every thing is fine and every thing is working as expected.

Comment: try removing this line 
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle". I think problem is because of this style.

Comment: tried this , but did not get desired results.

Comment: then check your spinner layout. maybe something is wrong there

Comment: try to set static value to  autoComplete.setDropDownWidth(500); and see it does make any differene or not?

Comment: Thanks dude. After spending two much time I figure out the property , that was inside the style.xml that was a culprit

Comment: @Androidteem how'd you fix it in the end